# How do I know current Action is pass authorized or not in ActionFilterAttribute on MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

As you know if we want to authorize we can rewrite **AuthorizeAttribute**, but currently I want to know current action is pass authorize or not in the **ActionFilterAttribute**

For example: This is for authorize:

```
public class AdminAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
     public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
     {
           // if authorize then continue, or else redirection the action to some page for some user
     }
}
```

This is for access Log, This is the place I want to know **current request is authorized or not**

```
public class LoggerFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
     // before save the access log, I want to know current request is authorized or not, then I can write the authorize status to the access log/
   }
}
```

**Update1:**

I'm **not use** the default User.Identity or Role.
I'm using my own authrize role from database and session.
For example:

```
public class AdminAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string ActionName {get; set;}
         public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
         {
              if (null == GetSession("AdminNo"))
                {
                    // Authorized failed. redirect
                }

              if (null == GetSession("RoleName")
                {
                   // Authorized failed. redirect
                }
              else{
                     if (!GetSession("ActionInRole").include(ActionName))
                     {
                        // Authorized failed. redirect
                     }
                  }

           // Authorized success.
         }
    }
```